# Graded commutative algebra with complex coefficients in Sage

Tags: python, sage

Is it possible to create graded commutative algebras with complex coefficients in Sage? When I try so,

```
A.<a,ia,abarra,iabarra,b,ib,bbarra,ibbarra>=GradedCommutativeAlgebra(CC,degrees=(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))
```

it gives me an error.

However it does work if I use rational coefficients:

```
A.<a,ia,abarra,iabarra,b,ib,bbarra,ibbarra>=GradedCommutativeAlgebra(QQ,degrees=(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))
```